# Windows 8 Login screen shows a key [after installation of Cisco AnyConnect VPN]

Tags: windows-8, cisco-vpn-client

After installing Cisco AnyConnect software each time I login I am presented with two boxes with keys in them, which I must click, and then I can enter my username and password.  In the security policy I enabled remember last username and disabled microsoft accounts.  Now instead of two keys I have one key, and my username is still not remembered.  Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I uninstalled Cisco AnyConnect Network Manager and the key is gone and I can enter my credentials (with remembered username too), but I like Network Manager too am am searching for what causes the key to be displayed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall and then reinstall the Cisco client.  I did that and it seems to work.

Comment: This answer might be better suited as a comment to the question asking for clarification.